# What field type?

Tags: sql, database

I know maybe this is a stupid question, But i suck at sql

But what field type should you have on a field that can only have numbers 1 to 5? 5 is max and 1 is min.
It's currently `int(11) not unsigned`

I heard having the wrong type can hurt performace

Edit: the database is InnoDB. RDBMS is MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your RDBMS, go with an integer that can hold a small value.

[MySQL has a `tinyint` datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html), which is of size 1 byte, and holds values 0-255 or -128 through 127.

[MySQL apparently doesn't have check constraints implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+check+constraint) in the current version, so you'll either have to enforce your 1-5 range requirement yourself in other code. There are some suggestions on writing a trigger to enforce this business logic.

You're correct on the datatype-hurting-performance, but in this case, it's unlikely to apply. Consider this a micro-optimization, but still worth considering.

Comment: Holy cow! MySQL doesn't honor check constraints?! That's a core tool for implementing data integrity. That's practically criminal.

Answer (score 0):

What database platform?

I would generally choose the smallest and add a check constraint for good measure for data quality/integrity.

For SQL Server, that would be tinyint (0-255).